# Error in getting time difference in milliseconds

Tags: excel

In G19 I have 03/14/2022 18:35:33:5789 and in G18 I have 03/14/2022 18:35:33.2837. I have a custom category for this column of mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.0. In my D19, I placed this formula

```
=G19-G18
```

Why am I getting an error on this.

```
A value used in this formula is of the wrong data type
```

I even formatted this D19 to hh:mm:ss.0

Comment: `03/14/2022 18:35:33:5789` this seems not actual date time. Last colon `:` need to be replaced by dot `.` So, it would be `03/14/2022 18:35:33.5789`

Comment: I did that already Sir.